# Plotting a partial sum (Fourier Series)

Tags: plotting, summation

This is what I'd like to plot:

```
Plot[{(5/8) + 
   Sum[((2*Cos[((n*Pi)/2) ] - (n*Pi*Sin[(n*Pi)/2]) - 
         1)/((n^2)*(Pi^2)))*(Cos[(n*Pi*x)])]}, {n, 1, 20}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

but for some reason I'm getting an error message that says

> Plot::nonopt: Options expected (instead of {x,0,1}) beyond position 2 in Plot[{5/8+Sum[((Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]-1) Cos[n [Pi] x])/Times[<<2>>]]},{n,1,20},{x,0,1}]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules. >>

Could someone please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Basically, you're not matching up parentheses, square brackets, and curly braces correctly. Look through your code carefully. In addition---and this may just be a copy-and-paste problem, but you need to separate your variables with either spaces or *'s if you are multiplying quantities, e.g. `nPiSin` needs to be `n*Pi*Sin`. If you fix these problems, your function will plot.

Comment: Thank you, just got it. How would I add nmax= 20 and 80 on the same graph? So right now I have this :Plot[(5/8) + 
  Sum[((2*Cos[((n*Pi)/2) ] - (n*Pi*Sin[(n*Pi)/2]) - 
        1)/((n^2)*(Pi^2)))*(Cos[(n*Pi*x)]), {n, 1, 20}], {x, 0, 1}]     and it works, but it only gives me nmax=20, so how would I add nmax also equals 80? Thanks again and I apologize for the syntax.

Comment: Look up the documentation for `Plot`; there are examples to help you there. By the way two things: (1) please use proper code formatting when posting. For help, click the grey question mark on the toolbar above your post after clicking the edit button below your post (or when you are posting). (2) people here expect a minimum level of self-help; you've made a good start by posting the code that you tried (many first-time posters don't think to do this), but you should *always* check the *Mathematica* help files first. They are very good.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to write your expression with correct bracketing, which would be

```
Plot[5/8 + 
  Sum[((2*Cos[n*Pi/2] - n*Pi*Sin[n*Pi/2] - 1)*Cos[n*Pi*x])/(n^2*Pi^2), {n, 1, 20}], 
  {x, 0, 1}]
```

you would get

[image: plot]